# Angularjs Ajax Post to Epressjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, angularjs, express

I am trying to make a Ajax request from Angularjs to Express js. Below code is my angularjs and express js route.
The problem is I am getting 500 Server error when I make a POST and get seems to work without any problem

AngularJs code

```
$http.post('http://www.mydomin.com/abc',str)
.success(function(data) {
  alert(data);
})
.error(function(data) {
  alert(1);
});
```

Here str can be just a letter or anything str= 't'; for example

ExpressJs route

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.post('/abc', function(req, res) {
    console.log('ggg');
  });
};
```

This route is added to app.js as well

```
require('./routes/test')(app);
```

Comment: What give the networks console ?

Comment: What are the contents of str? You probably need to post JSON. Also, it's probably better if you use `$http.post('/abc', ...)`.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error 19ms angular.js (line 9002)
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:3000/abc"

Comment: str can be single letter also like say str = m;

Comment: Have you tried debugging the server? Where exactly is it failing?

Comment: have you set up any middleware to allow POST and/or a bodyParser?

Comment: I tried sending JSON data no luck...I guess something that I am missing some where...
It is not hitting the server, 500 is server not found if I am not wrong

Comment: Eric, Express.js bodyparse is enabled in the config

Comment: @user1577298 did you send the "JSON" from angular as a string or as an object? $http.post() is expecting an object.

Comment: @rob this is what I am sending
str='m';
var dataJ=JSON.stringify('name='+str);

Comment: 500 is internal server error, my guess would be your middleware is choking on the object you're sending.

Comment: What could be the issue?

Comment: post your server logs and you can see what error is causing the app to crash.

Comment: Fine guys..after a long search...had some issues with my app.js file..
Thank you for all the answers

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
$http.post('/abc',{name: str})
    .success(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
});
require('./routes/test')(app);

app.listen(3000);
```

routes/test.js

```
module.exports = function(app){
app.post('/abc', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("ok");
});
}
```

This is a really basic app that should work without issue. Not sure where you are differing, but this is a bsic template to go off of.